# Edit Pages - Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: codeigniter

I wonder why I still having this error message appearing.

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/editpages.php

Line Number: 48

Backtrace:

File: C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\masterlinkci2\application\admin\views\editpages.php
Line: 48
Function: _error_handler

controllers/Cpages.php

```
 public function editpagesupdate() {

    $data['pagessuccess'] = '';

    $pages_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $data['pages'] = $this->Mpages->update_pages($pages_id);

    $this->load->view('editpages', $data); 

}
```

models/Mpages.php

```
public function update_pages($pages_id)
{

    $data = array(
        'pages_name' => $this->input->post('pages_name'),
        'create_date' => $this->input->post('create_date'),
        'pages_order' => $this->input->post('pages_order'),
        'pages_content' => $this->input->post('pages_content')
    );

    $this->db->where('pages_id', $pages_id);
    $query = $this->db->update('pages', $data);
    //return $query->result_array();
    return $query;

}
```

views/editpages.php

```
                <div class="widget-box">
                    <div class="widget-title"><h5>Pages</h5></div>
                    <div class="widget-content">

                    <?php echo form_open('cpages/editpagesupdate'); ?>
                    <table border="0" style="width: 100%; height: 90px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Pages Name</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="pages_name" value="<?php echo $pages_item['pages_name']; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Create Date</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="create_date" value="<?php echo $pages_item['create_date']; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr>
                            <td>Order</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="pages_order" value="<?php echo $pages_item['pages_order']; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>View Content</td>
                            <td><textarea rows="3" cols="20" name="pages_content"><?php echo $pages_item['pages_content']; ?></textarea></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><input type="submit" class="edit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>            
                    </div>
                </div>      

                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Is the error because your editpages.php has an `endforeach` but not a matching beginning `foreach`?

Comment: Because you have no get() in your model only update **"UPDATE returns TRUE OR FALSE" does not get data,** as we have said many times on your other accounts

Answer (score 0):

controllers/Cpages.php

```
public function editpagesupdate() {
    $data['pagessuccess'] = '';
    $pages_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $update = $this->Mpages->update_pages($pages_id);
    $data = array();

    /* get updated pages here */
    if($update){
       $data['pages'] = $this->Mpages->get_pages();
    }

    $this->load->view('editpages', $data); 
}
```

models/Mpages.php

```
public function get_pages()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('pages');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

views/editpages.php

```
 <div class="widget-box">
      <div class="widget-title"><h5>Pages</h5></div>
      <div class="widget-content">
           <?php echo form_open('cpages/editpagesupdate'); ?>
           <table border="0" style="width: 100%; height: 90px;">
                <?php foreach($pages as $pages_item) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pages Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="pages_name" value="<?php echo $pages_item['pages_name']; ?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Create Date</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="create_date" value="<?php echo $pages_item['create_date']; ?>"></td>
                </tr>   
                <tr>
                   <td>Order</td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="pages_order" value="<?php echo $pages_item['pages_order']; ?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>View Content</td>
                    <td><textarea rows="3" cols="20" name="pages_content"><?php echo $pages_item['pages_content']; ?></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" class="edit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>            
       </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you dont have the get_pages function correct. your missing `from()` and `get()` https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data

Comment: I changed the get_pages() function. Thank you for correcting me.